# FTP Client for Ubuntu that allows drag'n'drop?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Can someone recommend me an FTP client that will allow me to perform Drag and Drop operations onto my desktop or other folders on my system straight from the FTP Client that's connected to a server? Does one even exist? I've tried FileZilla on Windows before, and it allowed me to do so. Installed FileZilla on Ubuntu, attempted to drag and drop, and it did not work. Is there some setting I need to modify, or is there another FTP Client that can do so? Any suggestions? This would really make everything faster for me.

Comment: 2016, and the issue is still there. I cannot drag'n'drop a file from remote folder onto my desktop. Missing such a basic and extremely useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

just use the fie manager with ftp folder, open another local folder and drag files away!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant you tried filezilla and it didn't work for some reason. I believe FireFTP works for this if you use firefox.